# Flutter : How to read video "mp4" file from a special path

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi everyone i build flutter app to download video .

the app save all video in this path :

> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.test.play/files/

and now i work to video downloaded page

how can i read just videos in app path
and display the videos in list ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) to pick multiple files.

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: true);

if (result != null) {
  List<File> files = result.paths.map((path) => File(path)).toList();
} else {
  // User canceled the picker
}
```

or if you want to pick files with extension filter

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
  type: FileType.custom,
  allowedExtensions: ['mp4'],
);
```